# How to deal with the multicollinearity between two significant independent variables?

Tags: r, linear-regression, correlation

I' m now building a linear regression model. There are 32 independent variables. G3 is the target variable.
[image: structure of the dataset]

Firstly, I build the linear regression model by using all independent variables. This is the part of results I got:
[image: results of linear regression model with all independent variables]

As you can see, both G1 and G2 are significant independent variables. But the correlation between them is  0.8521181. So i think multicollinearity exists in the linear regression model. I'm now going to find the best linear regression model. How can i solve the multicollinearity issue?

Comment: Why do you assume there are difficulties? Have you done any model diagnostics? Plotting of residuals? Examination of predictions at ends of ranges of independent variables? I suggest you research best practices for handling multicollinearity on CrossValidated.com since that is the place to go to improve your stats skills (and that's my "close vote") and learn better practices. Come back here when you have a coding question.

Comment: use a LASSO or other shrinkage method, the `glmnet` package is a good starting point.

Comment: If you want to remove collinearity between just G1 and G2, then do PCA on them to get a single variable that accounts for both G1 and G2.

Answer (score 1):

If multicollinearity is a problem in your model the solution may be relatively simple. Try one of these:

- Remove highly correlated predictors from the model.  If you have two or more factors highly correlated, remove one from the model. Because they supply redundant information, removing one of the correlated factors usually doesn't drastically reduce the R-squared. Consider using stepwise regression, best subsets regression, or specialized knowledge of the data set to remove these variables. Select the model that has the highest R-squared value.
- Use Partial Least Squares Regression (PLS) or Principal Components Analysis, regression methods that cut the number of predictors to a smaller set of uncorrelated components.